# How to import a component in Yew?

Tags: rust, yew

So I have a `main.rs` file that looks like so:

```
fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

But I need to import the App component into `main.rs`. From what I saw in a tutorial I should be able to do: `use <name_of_app>::App;`, but that does not work. It will tell me that <name_of_app> is not a part of the crate for me to use and Rust analyzer is not coming up with suggestions.

I tried this approach, but Rust analyzer is complaining that `App` is being defined multiple times:

```
mod App;
use App::App;

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

Comment: @kmdreko, yes but I did not want to name my file `lib.rs`, so I named it `App.rs`. Can I not get away with that? As a ReactJS developer I am trying to organize the project the way I would ordinarily do if it was a React project.

Comment: I deleted by comment about `lib.rs`, but you may not be aware that `main.rs` and `lib.rs` are *special* files in a cargo project. So renaming it did more than you think.

Comment: @kmdreko, you are right, I was not aware of that.

Comment: *"Rust analyzer is complaining that `App` is being defined multiple times"* - ha, that's funny. You should probably follow convention and use lowercase file names (`app.rs` and `mod app;`, `use app::App;`) to avoid this problem.

Comment: @kmdreko, using Rust convention of a lowercase `app.rs` worked. Making note of convention. Thank you.

Comment: Or you can get rid of the `use App::App;` line and type `App::App` everywhere, e.g. `yew::Renderer::<App::App>::new().render();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define a module for whatever file your `App` is defined in. `mod name_of_app; use name_of_app::App;`

src/main.rs

```rust
mod module_for_app;
use module_for_app::App;

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

src/module_for_app.rs

```rust
pub struct App {
   // ....
}
```

See the [section from The Book on modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html) for more information

Comment: my App function is defined in the App file. `mod App::App` is not going to go down well with Yew. Can you suggest a better naming convention in the world of Rust? I am a React developer so I am really approaching this file organization in a ReactJS way.

Comment: @Daniel you did not read the answer correctly. If your `App` is in `App.rs` then you need *both* `mod App;` (to declare it) and `use App::App;` (to import it)

Comment: @kmdreko, check out my original post, I edited it, perhaps than can clarify things and help you, help me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, but I solved it in a different way, I hope you can refer to the following.

I have wrapped the render method of the App component inside the component file,like `app.rs`

```
#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
  // some code
}

pub fn render() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

then in `main.rs`, you can use app mod and call `app::render()`

```
mod app;

fn main() {
    app::render();
}
```